# GitHub Pages showing ReadMe file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

I have my ruby on rails project on github and want to show it on pages but it only shows whats in the readme file.

I've read through other stack overflow questions about this but I don't really understand how to fix it. My rails app is on https://github.com/obvJones/railstesting/.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/054df.png)
This is what my pages settings look like

Comment: What other pages do you want to show? Where do you expect them to show?

Comment: are you deploying a branch? It looks like you are just deploying your repo which would show your main README file.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to host a static website on [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) using Ruby language, it is only possible through [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/). So it's not possible to run a Rails server on Github Pages. If you want more details on how to do that, please take a look at this [Setting up a GitHub Pages site with Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)

Comment: Guide also available in Deutsch (https://docs.github.com/de/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)